# JS обработчик из 2-x одинаковых select срабатывает на последнем

Tags: javascript, select, placeholder

Имеется код из шаблона:

```
<body class="color-7">
<div class="container">
<section><select class="cs-select cs-skin-boxes">
<option value="" disabled selected>Число</option>
<option value="1" data-class="1">1</option>
<option value="2" data-class="2">2</option>
</select></section>
<section><select class="cs-select cs-skin-boxes">
<option value="" disabled selected>Цвет</option>
<option value="#588c75" data-class="color- 
588c75">#588c75</option>
<option value="#b0c47f" data-class="color- 
b0c47f">#b0c47f</option>
</select><section>
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="js/selectFx.js"></script>
<script>
(function () {
[].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'select.cs-select') ).forEach( 
function(el) {
new SelectFx(el, {
stickyPlaceholder: true,
onChange: function(val){
document.querySelector('span.cs- 
placeholder').style.backgroundColor = val;
}
});
});
})();
</script>
</body>


                `
```

3-ий день мучаюсь не знаю как сделать чтоб срабатывал тот или другой select **по своим option**. Оба работают но только по option последнего select. В JS новичок-[].slice.call и прототипирование пока не для меня(((. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: "но только по option последнего select" - что это значит?

Comment: это значит при запуске открывается 2 placeholder: в 1-ом "Число", во 2-ом "Цвет". Кликаю на "Число" - в обоих появляется цвет:

Comment: То, что Вы описываете, не может происходить в коде, включенном в вопрос. В нем вооще нет никаких `span`-ов.

Comment: Там есть подключаемый js/selectFx.js, он, видимо, этим и занимается. В Хроме, в "инструментах разработчика" вижу в section появление div class="cs-select cs-skin-boxes" tabindex="0",в нем span class="cs-placeholder" style="background-color. могу выложить selectFx.js, но он длинный!?((

Comment: Вы не могли бы объяснить, какое поведение является целью данного кода?

Comment: попытаюсь: код переоформлял select в placeholder c текстом "Цвет", при клике на него разворачивался на весь экран к набор прямоугольников из ul,  при клике на 1 прямо-ник placeholder менял цвет на выбранный, текст менялся на код цвета...мне понравилось для моих целей, нужно чтоб также было и с добавленным новым select...один обработчик на один из двух выбранных select...вроде просто, но не могу решить

Answer (score 0):

я не работал selectFx.js и classie.js, я их загрузил и проверил Ваш код.

1. до вызова script не доходило пока я не закрыл теги `</section>` и `</div>` (`</section>` был без закрывающего слэша, а закрывающего `</div>` вообще не было)
2. скрипт должен находить элементы с классом cs-select и навешивать на него обработчик onChange. Там вызывается анонимная функция function () (просто функция без названия), в которой создаётся безымянный массив `[].slice.call...`, потом пробегает по каждому элементу массива с помощью `forEach`, и для каждого элемента выполняет функцию `function(el)` которая на события `onChange` (изменение) через `SelectFx`, навешивает обработчик:

   `function(val){
     document.querySelector('span.cs- 
     placeholder').style.backgroundColor = val;
   }`

"Навешивание" обработчика происходило, но при выборе элементов (Число, Цвет) функция `function(val){...` не вызывалась

Ибо тоже не гуру, я переписал скрипт на более длинный, но надеюсь понятный:

```
<script>
            var a = document.querySelectorAll( 'select.cs-select');
            console.log(a);//смотрим какие элементы были найдены
            //меняю forEach на более понятный цикл (только в познавательных целях!! 
            //а так forEach сильно рулит)
            var i = a.length;//кол-во эл-тов в массиве
                while (i-- !=0) {//перебираю элементы
                    //addEventListener применил чтобы обработчик действительно
                    //присваивался (иначе (выше) обработчик не срабатывал)
                    a[i].addEventListener('change', function(el) {
                            new SelectFx(el, {stickyPlaceholder: true,
                                        onChange: function(val){
                                            document.querySelector('span.cs-placeholder').style.backgroundColor = val;
                                            }
                                        });
                    }, false);            
                }
</script>
```

Обработчики теперь вызываются при смене Число/Цвет, но эффектов я не получаю ибо в глубине `SelectFx` найденный мной элементы не имеют метода `querySelector`, о чём получаю ошибку в отладчике Хрома:

```
 selectFx.js:69 Uncaught TypeError: this.el.querySelector is not a function
    at SelectFx._init (selectFx.js:69)
    at new SelectFx (selectFx.js:46)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (yy.html:28)
```

Т.е. первое что я нашёл это НЕ вызов функции-обработчика при изменении элементов. Это поборол, дальше надо разбираться со строкой `document.querySelector('span.cs-placeholder').style.backgroundColor = val`

Comment: Круто...большая благодарность...тож копаю как могу